# Validate one of two fields to be present or none to be present based on value of another key

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

I have to validation based on some conditons:

If value of the key `pay_method` is `upi`, then ***one of the keys*** `services`

or `combos` must be present.

If value of the key `pay_method` is `pay_later`, then ***none of those keys*** should be present.

I tried combining `.when` and `.xor` also `.when` and `.oxor`.

But, I am not able to achieve the desired result.

```
Joi.object({
    pay_method: Joi.string().valid('upi', 'later').required(),
    combos: Joi.string().when('pay_method', {
      is: 'later',
      then: Joi.forbidden(),
    }),
    services: Joi.string().when('pay_method', {
      is: 'later',
      then: Joi.forbidden(),
    }),
  }).oxor('combos', 'services')
    .messages({ 'object.oxor': 'Both Combo and Service can not be ordered together!' })
```

Data to be validated:

```
{
  pay_method: 'later',
  combos: 'asdfasf',
}
```

According to the documentation:

`xor` : key names that must not appear together but where one of them is required

`oxor` : key names that must not appear together but where none are required

Please test here with above details https://joi.dev/tester/

Comment: did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The first two among the alternatives choose between having either combos or services when pay_method is 'upi'. The last one does not allow both combos and services to exist when pay_method is 'later'.

```
Joi.alternatives().try(
    Joi.object({
        pay_method: Joi.string().valid('upi').required(),
        combos: Joi.required(),
        services: Joi.forbidden()
    }),
    Joi.object({
        pay_method: Joi.string().valid('upi').required(),
        combos: Joi.forbidden(),
        services: Joi.required()
    }),
    Joi.object({
        pay_method: Joi.string().valid('later').required(),
        combos: Joi.forbidden(),
        services: Joi.forbidden()
    })
);
```